# Azure Devops - Classic Pipeline - OWASP Zap Scanner Test - Powershell Task

Tags: xml, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, devsecops

Trying to Convert ZAP XML to NUnit XML in Azure Devops Release pipeline for OWASP ZAP Security testing, getting following error in Powershell Task. Please help

```
2021-09-06T09:39:32.4736044Z ##[section]Starting: Convert ZAP XML to NUnit XML
2021-09-06T09:39:32.4744197Z ==============================================================================
2021-09-06T09:39:32.4744531Z Task         : PowerShell
2021-09-06T09:39:32.4744804Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
2021-09-06T09:39:32.4745074Z Version      : 2.190.0
2021-09-06T09:39:32.4745298Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-09-06T09:39:32.4745622Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
2021-09-06T09:39:32.4746679Z ==============================================================================
2021-09-06T09:39:32.6192068Z Generating script.
2021-09-06T09:39:32.6225079Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2021-09-06T09:39:32.6236523Z [command]/usr/bin/pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command . '/home/vsts/work/_temp/55afabcf-833e-4c93-8d60-c067a14be9ab.ps1'
2021-09-06T09:39:33.5525712Z [91mTransformOWASPReport: [0m/home/vsts/work/r1/a/_Testing/Transform.ps1:28
2021-09-06T09:39:33.5527142Z [96mLine |
2021-09-06T09:39:33.5529111Z [96m  28 | [0m … ransformOWASPReport -XLSTPath $XLSTPath -OWASPFile [96m$OWASPFile[0m -Transf …
2021-09-06T09:39:33.5530107Z [96m     | [91m                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~
2021-09-06T09:39:33.5531096Z [91m[96m     | [91mCannot bind argument to parameter 'OWASPFile' because it is an
2021-09-06T09:39:33.5531923Z [96m     | [91mempty string.
2021-09-06T09:39:33.5781242Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2021-09-06T09:39:33.5816175Z ##[section]Finishing: Convert ZAP XML to NUnit XML
```

Comment: Please post your powershell code

Comment: try checking the Security test - https://dzone.com/articles/owasp-zap-security-tests-in-azure-devops-pipeline, also Check Zap Release pipeline - https://medium.com/@sudhinsureshr/azure-devops-configure-owasp-zap-in-release-pipeline-1a40b0f79e3b

Comment: Thanks for your response i have followed the links but facing the following error in Azure Devops Release pipeline

Comment: [command]/usr/bin/pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command . '/home/vsts/work/_temp/e7d92189-3fed-4c20-b768-b9d991d2e2b2.ps1'
[91mParentContainsErrorRecordException: [0m/home/vsts/work/_temp/e7d92189-3fed-4c20-b768-b9d991d2e2b2.ps1:6
[0m [96m$XslTransform.Load($XslPath)[
[91m ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[91mException calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Could not find
[91mfile '/home/vsts/work/r1/a/OWASPToNUnit3.xslt'."
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
##[section]Finishing: PowerShell Script

Answer (score -1):

The issue is resolved, we have given a correct path in PS variables.

Comment: please share some more details as I am also facing the same issue, while running the following script through pipeline 
$XslPath = "$($Env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY)/_Quality/SecurityTesting/OWASPToNUnit3.xslt"
$XmlInputPath = "$($Env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY)/OWASP-ZAP-Report.xml"
$XmlOutputPath = "$($Env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY)/Converted-OWASP-ZAP-Report.xml"
$XslTransform = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
$XslTransform.Load($XslPath)
$XslTransform.Transform($XmlInputPath, $XmlOutputPath)

Comment: Please share the error details :

Do you have the OWASP-ZAP-Report.xml file in SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY